# Change column values to item of a list of list python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change all my columns value for some items of my list of list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df 
Sitio,Country,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange
rgg,Perú,32,80   
rgg,Perú,30,49  
rgg,Estados Unidos,24,15

geos = [['Estados Unidos','US - Estados Unidos'],['Estonia','EE - Estonia']]
```

I'm trying to change all items of `df['Country'] to geo[1:]` if `item` of `df['Country'] == geo[:1]`

```
for geo in geos:
    for item in df['Country']:
        if item == geo[:1]:
            item = geo[1:]
```

I need something like this:

```
Sitio,Country,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange
rgg,Perú,32,80   
rgg,,Perú,30,49  
rgg,US - Estados Unidos,24,15
```

Comment: `df.Country.replace(dict(geos))`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Rather, `df.Country.replace(dict(geos), inplace=True)`.

Comment: it works but when I print `df`I see the same `df` as before @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: `df = df.Country.replace(dict(geos))`

Comment: It's not working because remember I have more information also the `Country`as  `Sitio, Subastadas, Impresiones_exchange`@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: `df['Country'] = df.Country.replace(dict(geos))` Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: I'm trying to save the csv with `encoding='ascii'` or `encoding='utc-8'` but I'm still seeing `PE - PerÃº`, how can I fix it? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: `encoding='latin-1'`?